# How to find the functions in a source file for an added library to Python

Tags: python, mql5, mql, metatrader5

I have recently installed Python and MetaTrader5 library, and I am trying to further understand how this library connects to the MetaTrader terminal and handles my requests. I am pretty new to programming in general and do not have much experience with viewing source code for external libraries.

As an example, there is a function mt5.account_info() that I would like to locate in the library source code yet all I have in my files is the __ init__ that contains only 4 functions that are not even listed when I run print(dir(mt5)). How do I go about finding the code for these functions that the MetaTrader5 library uses?

My overall goal is to be able to use the ObjectGetDouble function that isn't part of the Python integration and I am trying to see if I can add this function myself or if I need to do it in the MQL editor and export the data that way.

I have tried looking through the source code in the installed library folders but have not found the resources. I am not familliar with C++ so I haven't been able to write any MQL5 code in order to extract the ObjectGetDouble information.

Comment: If you type `pip show <library-name>` where <library-name> is the library in question, this will show where the library is installed; thus where to search for the source code. Once there, you can use a search tool (e.g. grep, if you have access to GNU tools) to search for the function in question.

Comment: The issue is that I only find the __ init__ file under the env\lib\site-packages\MetaTrader5 and nothing else. And within that file the functions I seek do not exist. Only 4 functions exist within that file and none are the main ones that [The documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5) shows as available.